# Try and catch method, python, indentation error can't figure it out

Tags: python, try-catch

```
 #setBirthday sets their Birthday to a date
    def setBirthday(self):
        while True:
            try:
                day = int(raw_input('Please enter the date of the month (1-31) you were born on here ->'))
                if day <= 0 or day >= 32:
                    print "better try again..."
            except ValueError:
                
                continue
            else:
                break

                month = int(raw_input('Please enter the month of the year (1-12) you were born on here ->'))
                if month <= 0 or day >= 13:
                    print "better try again..."
            except ValueError:
                
                continue
            else:
                break
                year = int(raw_input('Please enter the year you were born (19xx or 20xx) here ->'))
                
                self.birthday = datetime(year, month, day)
                print str(varPerson.getName()) + " you were born on " + str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)
```

The indentation error is just above varPerson the last 3 lines. I have tried and tried to get this scenario working with exceptions to be able to have a smooth running script that allows for additional tries if value is not appropriate. Suggestions? I have been using this link for help:

[Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: this is running in windows..

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88:  pardon?  The `if __name__ == '__main__':` is optional on all platforms.

Comment: Why did you put a bunch of method definitions in a loop? And a `try`? Were you expecting the definitions to go wrong and need to be redone?

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88: no it is not.  If I'm wrong, show me where that is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want handle any exceptions, try below code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = None


#getName returns the name of the person         
    def getName(self):
        return self.name        

#setBirthday sets their Birthday to a date
    while True:
        try:

            def setBirthday(self):
                while True:
                    try:
                        day = int(raw_input('Please enter the date of the month (1-31) you were born on here ->'))
                        month = int(raw_input('Please enter the month of the year (1-12) you were born on here ->'))
                        year = int(raw_input('Please enter the year you were born (19xx or 20xx) here ->'))
                        self.birthday = datetime(year, month, day)
                        print str(varPerson.getName()) + " you were born on " + str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)
                    except ValueError:
                        print "better try again...return to the start of the loop"
                        continue
                    else:
                        break
                #if day <= 0 or day >= 32:
                    #print "Please enter a number between 1 and 31. Try again." 

#getAge returns how many days old the individual is     
            def getAge(self):
                dateNow = datetime.now()
                dateBirth = self.birthday
                timedelta = dateNow - dateBirth
                print str(varPerson.getName()) + " you have been living on Earth for " + str(timedelta)
#current date - birthdate to get specific days, timedelta
        except:
            pass


varPerson = Person(raw_input('Please enter your name here ->'))
varPerson.setBirthday()
varPerson.getAge()
```

Personally, While True is not good to use...

Comment: ok if you remove the first while True:, try and the last except statement and adjust the indentation this works.

Answer (score 5):

- Your outer try block does not have a corresponding except block.
- It doesn't make sense have a while or try block directly in a class definition. They must be inside a method definition.
- You cannot define methods inside a while block in a class.

Instead of trying to fix the above as they stand, try taking a good look at your code and figuring out what it is that you want to do. Then, ask how to best implement that big-picture objective-focused question on StackOverflow or another StackExchange site, showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: ok well I must be really tired, I totally missed that. Thanks. I'll try removing that...its always something obvious...

Comment: @Staley What exactly was the problem? Can you confirm that your code snippet in the question was correct? There is a chance even with this question that future viewers might find the question useful. You may also accept my answer using the green checkmark if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you defining setBirthday in a loop?

```
while True:
    try:

        def setBirthday(self):
            while True:
                try:
```